# Jest/Enzyme Test Prop Change onClick

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Using 16.8.0-alpha.0 so I can use React Hooks.

I have a parent component that sets collapsed to true or false on a click on a child component using react hooks:

```
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
```

The setCollapsed function just inverts the value of collapsed - true or false.

I'm testing the child component (the one that runs the setCollapsed function) in Jest using Enzyme.

How can I mock or trigger the setCollapsed function to change the collapsed prop that is passed into the child component I'm testing.

A simple version of the structure is:

```
const DefaultLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Sidebar collapsed={collapsed} setCollapsed={setCollapsed} />
      <Layout>
        <Header collapsed={collapsed} setCollapsed={setCollapsed} />
        <Content style={{ paddingTop: 0, margin: '24px' }}>{children}</Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

In Header.js:

```
const Header = ({ collapsed, setCollapsed }) => (
  <HeaderCollapsed onClick={() => setCollapsed(!collapsed)} role="presentation">
    <Icon type={collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'} />
  </HeaderCollapsed>
);
```

I've tried this:

```
let collapsedMock = true;
const setCollapsedMock = jest.fn(() => (collapsedMock = !collapsedMock));

describe('test Avatar component', () => {    
  it('changes collapsed prop on click', () => {
    const header = mount(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header collapsed={collapsedMock} setCollapsed={setCollapsedMock} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
    const collapser = header.find('HeaderCollapsed');
    collapser.prop('onClick')();
    header.update();
    console.log(header.props().children.props.collapsed);
    // expect(header.prop('collapsed')).toEqual(false);
    header.unmount();
  });
});
```

But the prop never updates from true.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are testing compund component and expecting props, rather test like :

```js
const header = mount(
                 <Header collapsed={collapsedMock} setCollapsed={setCollapsedMock}/>, <optional-context>
              );
```

and supply props needed from `BrowserRouter` explicitly

Comment: if possible pls send code sandbox, I would help you fix it.